# Binding to TextBlock in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I don't know if my understanding of binding is just poor or if I am not seeing the problem, but I hope someone can help me out here. I have a `ListView` with a template of an image and a `TextBlock`, I need the `TextBlock` to be bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`. However when I run this I get nothing shown, I don't even see my `image` that I have set.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontFamily">MS Reference Sans Serif</FontFamily>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Facies}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="../Images/Shale.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FaciesName}" Width="75" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class FaciesControl : UserControl
{

    public FaciesControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<string> Facies {get; set;}

    public void Bind(string[] data)
    {
        Facies = new List<string>();
        Facies.AddRange(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set `DataContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set `DataContext` like this:

```
public FaciesControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string[] str = { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };
    Bind(str); // Make sure you have called the Bind method
    DataContext = Facies;
}
```

Second change your XAML like this:

```
<ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
 ....
 ....
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="75" Margin="5"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that was perfect :)